# Ninject - Kernel in static class?

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

Is it right at all to "wrap" a `StandardKernel` with the required `NinjectModule`s in a static class in a separate, shared library, and use that same library whenever injection is needed (instead of instantiating a new kernel everytime)?

Edit: I am trying to use Ninject from within the WCF service I am developing at the moment.

(Please bear with me if what I am saying is completely rubish since I just started learning about DI and IoC containers)

Comment: What type of application are you building and what framework are you using? (ASP.NET MVC/WebForms, Silverlight, WFP, WinForms)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. It's WCF. I am going to edit the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf . This extension will create the WCF service using the Ninject kernel. That way you can use constructor injection instead of using the Service Locator pattern.