# Ninject - Kernel in static class in class librarary project

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have the same question as [Ninject - Kernel in static class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628365/ninject-kernel-in-static-class)
but I am not using WCF, only a class library.

Is it better to have a static kernel or to instantiate it any time you want?
My UI (now in an MVC application) consumes the service, so will it call  the static kernel? 
What is the best approach?

Answer (score 6):

When using IoC, the preferred approach is to use the kernel as little as possible. It should be used at initialisation time to hook everything up, and after that fade quickly and quietly into the background. Thus where the "Hollywood Principle" is applied: "Don't call the IoC container, let it call you!". Static classes containing the kernel are what's known as the Service Locator anti-pattern, see [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

In short: You'll want to use constructor injection to inject dependencies instead of creating a kernel each time, or referencing a static class.

Comment: You'll want to use constructor injection to inject dependencies instead of creating a kernel each time, or referencing a static class.
Can you explain this please ? how the kernel will intecept constructors if the kernel him self is not instantiated ?

Comment: At initialisation time you use the kernel to new up any services with dependencies, and perhaps some kernel-backed factories to produce instances of particular types, after that all you need to access is the services or factories, it *appears* like there is no IoC container involved.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Ninject for MVC extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc), so why not to use it for MVC UI?

And WCF service could has his own [*composition root*](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx). For sure, you could reuse one `NinjectModule` implementation in both of them. So there is no need for `Kernel` to be static, just reuse `NinjectModule` implementation in every *composition root*.

For example, you application configuration:

```
public class ApplicationModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IAbstraction>().To<Implemtation>();
        //  and other general bindings
    }
}
```

[MVC with Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc):

```
public class YourWebApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
  public override IKernel CreateKernel()
  {
     var kernel = new StandardKernel(new ApplicationModule ());

     // add some UI specific bindings, for example authorization
     kernel.Bind<IAuthProvider>().To<AuthProvider>();

     // binding between service contract and implementation/client
     kernel.Bind<IServiceContract>().To<WcfServiceClient>();

     return kernel;
  }
}
```

And [WCF with Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf/blob/Maintenance_2.2/src/Examples/WcfTimeService/Global.asax.cs):

```
public class Global : NinjectWcfApplication
{
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new ApplicationModule ());

        // add some service specific bindings, for example authorization
        // service has also some other small services that i call providers 
        // so ex Service 1 : has Iprovider1 Iprovider2 Iprovider3 
        kernel.Bind<IProvider1>().To<Provider1>();
        kernel.Bind<IProvider2>().To<Provider2>();
        kernel.Bind<IProvider3>().To<Provider3>();

        return kernel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i really don't understand.
Yes i use ninject and mvc in the UI to choose the appropriate service implementation.
The fact is that in my service i have also some other small services that i call providers 
So ex Service 1 : has Iprovider1 Iprovider2 Iprovider3 ...
So i want in the service inject the correct providers (static, from DB, for Test)
Hope you understand me.

Comment: There are two questions: 1. are MVC and `Service1` at same `AppDomain`? 2. are they from same source code tree? If at least first is 'yes', one `Kernel` could injects everything. If first is 'no', but they are from same source tree (second is 'yes') configuration could be reused. Anyway, creating of one static `Kernel` will introduce additional dependency, but not to resolve it.

Comment: No MVC and Service are not in the same library, MVC talk to Contracts library (which defines public interfaces of the service layer)
That"s why i want the mvc choose the right service with ninject, but in one service i can inject the correct provider
I think i will make everything public and use Ninject to inject dependency for services and providers
Is it the right thing to do ?

Comment: Ok, here is updated sample. It has common configuration for whole project `ApplicationModule`, and to custom _composition roots_ for UI and service with separate bindings. You could extend this sample with _Convention over Configuration_ and autodiscovery.

Comment: Thanks akim, really appreciate your help, i will try to understand composition root and i will give you feed back

Comment: Btw, Mark Seemann has [great book about DI](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) — good place to start learning

Answer (score 0):

Mark Seemann's says in his blog here http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx
Only applications should have Composition Roots. Libraries and frameworks shouldn’t.

That's answer my question, i understand better the composition root pattern.
Thank's for help Akim and Alexander R